# Inserting existing column value into a new table when updating the existing value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm new to SQL Server.

I need a one answer that it is, I have a table `tblemployee` and the columns are

```
empid,
name,
paddr1,
paddr2,
pcity,
pstate,
pzip,
caddr1,
caddr2,
ccity,
cstate,
czip
```

I have a another table `tblpaddresshistory` and the columns are

```
paddrlistid,
paddr1,
paddr2,
pcity,
pstate,
pzip
```

and I have yet another table `tblcaddresshistory` with these columns

```
caddrlistid,
caddr1,
caddr2,
ccity,
cstate,
czip
```

Here is my question: when I'm updating the `tblemployee` of column values `paddr1, paddr2, pcity, pstate, pzip, caddr1, caddr2, ccity, cstate, czip`, the old values should be inserted into `tblpaddresshistory` and `tblcaddresshistory` and new values should be updated in `tblemployee`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask a proper question and get answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try with this trigger

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_tblemployee
ON dbo.tblemployee
AFTER UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
      IF ( UPDATE(paddr1)
            OR UPDATE(paddr2)
            OR UPDATE (pcity)
            OR UPDATE(pstate)
            OR UPDATE(pzip) )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.tblpaddresshistory
                        (paddr1,
                         paddr2,
                         pcity,
                         pstate,
                         pzip)
            SELECT paddr1,
                   paddr2,
                   pcity,
                   pstate,
                   pzip
            FROM   deleted;
        END

      IF ( UPDATE(caddr1)
            OR UPDATE(caddr2)
            OR UPDATE (ccity)
            OR UPDATE(cstate)
            OR UPDATE(czip) )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.tblcaddresshistory
                        (caddr1,
                         caddr2,
                         ccity,
                         cstate,
                         czip)
            SELECT caddr1,
                   caddr2,
                   ccity,
                   cstate,
                   czip
            FROM   deleted;
        END
  END;
```